# How do I get value from edittext or text field in MapBasic

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have created a dialog menu in MapBasic which user can enter value in text field. I am a newbie in MapBasic Programming. My question is how to select data from database using text field value?

> select * from voronoi where Ha >=  inputnumber

That inputnumber is text field. Please I need your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me expand on my previous answer to show how to get the value from the EDITTEXT control. First create your dialog box using a dialog statement like below.

```
Dim inputText as String

Dialog
    Control STATICTEXT
        ID 1
        Title "Enter a valid number:"
    Control EDITTEXT
        ID 2
        Into inputText
    Control OKBUTTON
        ID 3
```

Now you need to check whether the OK button was pressed and if so, then you can do your selection using the value stored in `inputText`. You will need to convert the value to a number using the `Val()` function. Be careful, the `Val()` function will return 0 if the value in `inputText` is not a valid number so you may want to check this first.

```
If CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_DLG_OK) then
    Select * from Voronoi where Ha >= Val(inputText)
End if
```

Comment: It contains error "Val: argument1 has invalid type"

What does it means?

Comment: It means that `inputnumber` is not a valid type for the Val() function. I'm not sure without seeing a bit more of the code why that is - can you post the part of the code where inputnumber is assigned?

Comment: MapBasic has some neat function for formatting numbers (FormatNUmber$()) and deformating numbers DeformatNumber$(). They might come in handy here, too. The first will add grouping digits and decimal digits set in the Region Settings to the value and return a string with these. The second will assume the string has grouping digits and decimal digits and convert these back. You still need to use the Val() function to cast it to a numeric value.